# search JSON in var jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, search

so i have stored a JSON in a varible but how do I search it, basiclly when a user clicks the name of the business I want to load and show them the store address, phone number and other details.

here is the var

```
var myMarkers = {
    "markers": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Belconnen",
        "url_name": "belconnen",
        "address": "Shop 176, 3rd Floor, Westfield Shopping Centre, Benjamin Way",
        "suburb": "Belconnen",
        "state": "act",
        "postcode": 2618,
        "country": "Australia",
        "phone": "(02) 6251 1838",
        "fax": "",
        "photo": "dcddfcb5c806b2255c611bd2d108cead.JPG",
        "text": "",
        "display": 1,
        "lat": -35.238428606,
        "lng": 149.065917134,
        "email": "tc.belconnen@telechoice.com.au",
        "dealer_code": 63014,
        "region_id": 3,
        "type": 4
    }
]
```

I have removed most of the JS for easy.

This is the first time I have every tried to search and store the JS, normally i would get PHP to do it, but thought be easier and faster to get JS.

Comment: Are you able to modify the JSON?  Are you generating it yourself or getting it from a third party? If it's your JSON, consider autocomplete: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For searching any particular entry you can do something like this:

```
var target = 'Belconnen'; // value of target will change depending on click

$.each(myMarkers.markers, function() {
  if(this.name.toLowerCase() == target.toLowerCase()) {
    console.log(this.address);
    console.log(this.state); // and more
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access a property of an object by using `object.property` or `object['property']` syntax (the two are synonymous, the second allows you to use an expression).

So in your case you would get the address like this:

```
var address = myMarkers.markers[0].address;
```

Use similar code to get at the other information you want.

Comment: I understand this, however how do I do a myMarkers.markers search say I want to search for Belconnen and only show their info

Comment: @RussellHarrower - You just need to use a looping construct to loop through the JSON and use an if statement to find the property you're looking for. That's the simplest route.

Comment: You would loop through the markers - `var l = myMarkers.markers.length; for( var i=0; i<l; i++) { if( myMarkers.markers[i].name == "Belconnen") { /* do stuff */ break; } }`

Comment: @Kolink - Consider putting that in your answer instead of a comment, as it's more readable that way. +1 Exactly what I was thinking.